# Brackets live preview

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

I am using a portable version of brackets. The live preview is not working. It shows this error message saying Google chrome wasn't found and to install it. Is there a way I can use live preview with this portable Brackets Folder on any system that has Chrome installed?

Edit: Live preview works alright when I install Brackets to the system, but it is still not working with the extracted portable folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating CSS in Live Preview does not work when `<link> has type="text/css"` so remove that from the `<head>`. As well, there are several conditions that must be met to satisfy the Live Preview: for example, 1 syntax error will prevent Live Preview. This is explained in detail [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#livedev).

Check out [this](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/brackets/live-preview) resource, which explains how to use the `terminal` to modify IDE settings.